# How can we do unit testing asynchronous functions using test package in angulardart?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, testing, dart, angular-dart

I tried creating async function using angulardart code which will call internal service and from service will return response from a test url. How will i mock the particular function getUserDetails().

**login_component.html**

```
<div class="container">
   <button type="button" (click)="getUserDetails()">Click me to see 
     details
   </button>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let user of userDetails">{{user.id}}</div>
```

**login_component.dart:**

```
Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
 try {
   userDetails = await _loginService.userDetails();
   print(userDetails);
 } catch (e) {
   errMsg = e.toString();
 }
}
```

**login_service.dart:**

```
Future<dynamic> userDetails() async {
    var _url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    try {
      var res = await _http.get(_url);
      var response = _extractData(res).map((value) => new 
      List.fromJson(value)).toList();
      return response;
       } catch (e) {
         print(e);
        }
}
dynamic _extractData(Response resp) => JSON.decode(resp.body);
```

**list.dart**

```
class List {
  int id;
  String name;
  List(this.id, this.name);
  factory List.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> list) =>
  new List(list['id'], list['name']);
  Map toJson() => {'id': id, 'name': name};
}
```

Please help me in finding out solution. Also how can i check the test code coverage in angulardart ?

Comment: Proper formatting could make the code more readable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the comment . I have formatted the code . Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has many facets and dimensions, not all of which can be addressed concisely. But here are some guidelines:

- *"How can we do unit **testing asynchronous functions** using test package ...?"*

  The [test package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test) uniformly supports writing both synchronous
  and async tests. For details, see the package readme section 
  on [Asynchronous Tests](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test#asynchronous-tests).
- *"How can we do unit testing ... in AngularDart?"*

  - To test AngularDart **services** you can get by with 
    using the [test package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test) only.
  - You can write tests for AngularDart **components** with
    the help of the [angular_test](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular_test) package.

  See the AngularDart [Testing Guide](https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/angular/guide/testing) Section on
  [Component Testing](https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/angular/guide/testing/component) for details.
- *"How will I mock the particular function getUserDetails()"*

  I'm assuming that you want to test your component, in which case you wouldn't want to mock the component's `getUserDetails()` method. Instead you'd **mock the service** that it uses (`LoginSerice`).

  The [Mockito](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mockito) package makes it very easy to create mocks.
  The Testing Guide section on 
  [Services: local, external, mock, real](https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/angular/guide/testing/component/services)
  explains how to write and use mock services.
- *"How can i check the test code coverage ...?"*

  Some other Dart projects I know use [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io),
  but I haven't used it personally.

The doc links I've given above are for **Angular 5**. The Angular 4 Testing Guide is [here](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/testing).

Comment: Thank you Patrice .. I was a bit confused on choosing the right documentation for doing angulardart test cases apart from documentation in dart website . Seems like no video tutorials are available which explains unit testing . Please share if you have any knowledge regarding that . Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not aware of any videos, sorry.